# Create a new variable instance each time I split a string in Python

Tags: python, split, bioinformatics, fasta, dna-sequence

I have a string into a variable `x` that includes `">"` symbols. I would like to create a new variable each time the string is splitted at the `">"` symbol.

The string I have in the variable `x` is as such (imported from a simple `.txt` file):

```
>AF1785813
GTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA
>AF1785815
GTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG
>AF1785814
GTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA
```

The expected output is:

```
print(var_1)

>AF1785813
GTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA

print(var_2)

>AF1785815
GTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG

print(var_3)

>AF1785814
GTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA
```

To achieve this I am using a simple `for` loop

```
count = 3
for v in range(0, count+1):
    globals()[f"var_{v}"] = x.split('>')
print(var_3)
```

This way I am successfully getting a new variable for each count (*each count is == to the number of* `">"`).

However the output I am currently getting is:

```
print(var_1)
        
['', 'AF1785813GTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA', 'AF1785815GTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG', 'AF1785814GTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA']
            
print(var_2)

['', 'AF1785813GTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA', 'AF1785815GTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG', 'AF1785814GTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA']
            
print(var_3)
        
['', 'AF1785813GTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA', 'AF1785815GTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG', 'AF1785814GTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA']
```

How can I troubleshoot the for loop in order to achieve the expected output?

Comment: Note that when you start naming variables with numeric suffixes (`_1`, `_2`, `_3`, etc) it means you should be using a list or some other collection which you can then index by number.

Comment: (a) You need a list, not a bunch of variables that are similarly named with numeric suffixes, as @steven mentioned. (b) Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use specialized, well-tested and widely used open-source tools specifically designed for these tasks, and handling a variety of edge cases. For example, use [Biopython](https://biopython.org/), specifically [`Bio.SeqIO`](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO). Biopython can be easily installed, for example using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to iterate the split result:

```
for i, token in enumerate(x.split('>')):
    # do not include empty string
    if token:
        globals()[f"var_{i}"] = token

# then deal with the vars
print(var_1)
print(var_2)
..
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `re.findall` here:

```py
import re

inp = """>AF1785813
GTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA
>AF1785815
GTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG
>AF1785814
GTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA"""

vars = re.findall(r'>[^>]+', inp)
print(vars)

# ['>AF1785813\nGTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA\n',
#  '>AF1785815\nGTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG\n',
#  '>AF1785814\nGTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA']
```

Note that `re.findall` returns all matches inside a single neat list, which can then be iterated or accessed later as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the regular expression match the `>` character followed by the characters on the line following it, up until the next `>` character or the end of the string.

`[^\n]*`: This matches zero or more characters that are not newline characters.

`[^>]*`: This matches zero or more characters that are not the > character.

```
import re

x = ">AF1785813\nGTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA\n>AF1785815\nGTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG\n>AF1785814\nGTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA"

substrings = re.findall(">[^\n]*\n[^>]*", x)

for i, substring in enumerate(substrings, start = 1):
    globals()[f"var_{i}"] = substring
```

output:

```
>>> print(var_1)
>>> print(var_2)
>>> print(var_3)

>AF1785813
GTGTGGAGGGAAAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA

>AF1785815
GTGTGGAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCATTCAG

>AF1785814
GTGTGGAGGTGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCAAGATCGCACCACTGCACTCCA
```

Comment: `enumerate()` has a `start` argument which would do away with the need for the `+1` later on.  Just pass `start=1`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it.